# Accessing capture groups during substitution

Tags: python, regex

I have a text file containing  decimal numbers throughout it and was wanting to round up any that have a decimal >= `0.5`, otherwise I want to truncate the decimal, e.g., `23.7897` becomes `24` and `17.2395` becomes `17`.

The < `0.5` case is not a problem for `re.sub`:

```
re.sub(r'(\d+)\.[0-4]\d*', r'\1', line)
```

however, for the >= `0.5` case, I was wondering if there was a way to manipulate the `\1` capture group during the substitution somehow? Is it stored anywhere so that it can be sent to a function, e.g.:

```
re.sub(r'(\d+)\.[5-9]\d*', roundUp('\1'), line)
```

where `roundUp()` returns a string representing the value `\1 + 1`.

Surely there is a way to just increment `\1` inline during substitution without having loop through the matches from `findall`, incrementing the integer part, then refinding the pattern with `re.sub` and subtitute it in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an arbitrary callable for the replacement, so does this work for you?

```
re.sub(r'\d+\.\d*', lambda match: str(int(round(float(match.group(0))))), line)
```